# Avoiding thread.sleep in code while unit testing with Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have methods which have multiple thread.sleep which last for 20 seconds at times. This is a business requirement. I am trying to unit test these methods, by mocking and skipping these sleeps so that tests can run faster and doesn't actually wait for 20 seconds. Using the moq framework.
Appreciate any ideas on how to implement this.

Comment: The least friction way for code that was not designed for testability would be to factor out the sleep call into a virtual method that can be mocked.

Comment: If duration of operation required to be 20 seconds, then most valuable test will test which run actual implementation. In case you want to test something which called between sleeps, extract those operations to a method or class which can be tested separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably no way to mock `Thread.Sleep` because it's a static method and those cannot be mocked with DynamicProxy based mocking Frameworks like moq.

One option would be to use Profiler API based tools like Microsoft Fakes (only in VS Enterprise) or Typemoq professional.

The better option is not to call `Thread.Sleep` directly in your business logic. What you can do instead is to introduce an Interface like this

```
public interface ISleepService
{
    void Sleep(int ms);
}
```

Then create a default implementation that you use in your code:

```
public class SleepService: ISleepService
{
    public void Sleep(int ms)
    {
       Thread.Sleep(ms);
    }
}
```

Add a dependency of ISleepService to your Business Logic

```
public class MyBusinessLogic()
{
    private ISleepService _sleepService;
    public MyBusinessLogic(ISleepService sleepService)
    {
        _sleepService = sleepSerivce;
    }

    public void MyBusinessMethod()
    {
        // your code
        _sleeService.Sleep(20000);
        // more code
    }
}
```

You can then easily mock the ISleepService in your unit tests and pass the real implementation in your production code

Answer (score 1):

You can actually introduce interface for Thread.sleep methods and this you can mock while writing UTs

```
 public interface IThreadSleep
{
    void Sleep(int milliSec);

}
```

You can have implementation , something like this

```
 public class ThreadSleep : IThreadSleep
{
    public void Sleep(int milliSec)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(milliSec);
    }
}
```

In your business class, just inject this interface and you can then mock Thread.sleep

```
 public class Class1
{
    IThreadSleep _threadSleep;
    public Class1(IThreadSleep threadSleep)
    {
        _threadSleep = threadSleep;

    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // 
        _threadSleep.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know actual code you have but at least to have some idea. You could wrap your `Thread.Sleep` into the `interface` and then inject that one to your business handler\controller. In the actual implementation use `Thread.Sleep`to actually wait but within the tests mock that `interface` to avoid `Thread.Sleep`. For example:

```
public interface IMySleepContext
{
    void Sleep(int milliseconds);
}

public class MySleepContext : IMySleepContext
{
    public void Sleep(int milliseconds)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
    }
}

public class MyController
{
    private readonly IMySleepContext _mySleepContext;

    public MyController(IMySleepContext mySleepContext)
    {
        _mySleepContext = mySleepContext;
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        //do something
        _mySleepContext.Sleep(20000);
        //do somethign
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
//Arrange
MyController mc = new MyController(Mock.Of<IMySleepContext>());

//Act
mc.MyMethod();

//Assert
//do assert
```